# Content Porter "PRIMARY KEY constraint PK_FILE_EXTENSIONS" error

Tags: content-porter-2009

I'm getting this error trying to import the "system administration>content configuration>multimedia types" in a new installation of tridion 2011 sp1. 
I'm using Content Porter 2009 sp2. The database is SqlServer 2008

In the log I get this, some tip?

```
10/28/2015 6:42:59 PM   [Information]   Importing System Administration items
10/28/2015 6:43:03 PM   [Error] <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="8004033F" Category="4" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false" MessageID="16137"><![CDATA[Unable to save Multimedia Type (tcm:0-0-0).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_4439</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:0-0-0</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="true"><![CDATA[Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FILE_EXTENSIONS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FILE_EXTENSIONS'.
No data found. [ETA_FILE_EXTENSIONS, C]
The statement has been terminated.]]></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false"><![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_MULTIMEDIA_TYPES_CREATE".]]><tcm:Token>EDA_MULTIMEDIA_TYPES_CREATE</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Details><tcm:CallStack><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader,RunBehavior,String)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String,DbAsyncResult)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult,String,Boolean)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Create(IdentifiableObjectData)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Create(UserContext,String)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>MultimediaType.Save</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Request.SaveItem</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Request</tcm:Location></tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details></tcm:Error>

10/28/2015 6:43:03 PM   [Information]   Import failed
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** SOLVED! I don't know why, but one multimedia type has a repeated file extension (ttf,TTF), and this make the import to fail this way.

Comment: Go ahead and change your edit to an answer and then this can be marked as "solved". Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED! I don't know why, but one multimedia type has a repeated file extension (ttf,TTF), and this make the import to fail this way.